# Getting multiple session object on hitting the API from same browser

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session, stateless

As I have learnt, if you request server for a resource, from same browser window, it returns same session ID unless you close it and request from a new window each time. But in below case I am getting a new session id each time I hit a sample API. Is it something to do with stateless behavior of REST API? Please clarify my understanding.

```
        @RequestMapping(path = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> login(@RequestBody UserCredential credential, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("session "+request.getSession().getId());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code looks like you have not actually logged in.
You are requesting to login.
This will definitely create a new session Id every time you print it.

Please follow below link to understand how login works with spring.

link : https://dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-example-for-user-registration-and-login-1